Regarding installing curtain rods
Have installed curtain rods without issues in the past on dry walls using the white/plastic anchors. However, this time around was finding it very difficult with the dry wall. As suggested online, used the 1/4 drill bit and it turned out to be too big even for the anchors. So, next tried with the smaller size drill and it was too small for the anchor and had to hammer the anchor in and then when I tried to drive the screw using the screw driver, it went half way through and would not go in further. Again tried to hammer and finally used the drill to drive the screw. It went in all the way in making it useless.
Appreciate any workarounds in this case or what others have done in this situation. Thanks for the suggestions or inputs in advance!

Please provide some photos of the work.

Sounds like you're using the plastic expanding wall anchors and not the threaded/spiral drywall anchors?  The screw probably stopped going in further because the anchor came loose and just spun.  The holes may or may not be too big now, but you could try the threaded drywall anchors.  Never use a drill to drive the screws, unless you're re-driving a screw that was removed.  The torque from the drill will overpower the anchor, causing it to just spin in place.
